# Is this system of inequalities (and equality) tractable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, mathematica, quantum-groups

I have some real parameters here. The $\mu_i$ - for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ - are 'convex coefficents' in that $\mu_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i}\mu_i=1$. The $x$ and $z$ are such that $x^2+z^2\leq 1$.

The inequalities are 
$$\begin{align}
-1 &<\mu_1-\mu_2-\mu_3+\mu_4-z\mu_5 &<1
\\-1&<\mu_1-\mu_2-\mu_3+\mu_4+z\mu_5&<1
\\ -1&<\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3+\mu_4-\mu_5&<1
\\ -1&<\mu_1-\mu_4+\sqrt{(\mu_2-\mu_3)^2+\frac{\mu_5^2x^2}{2}}&<1
\\-1&<\mu_1-\mu_4-\sqrt{(\mu_2-\mu_3)^2+\frac{\mu_5^2x^2}{2}}&<1
\end{align}$$

I have put these five inequalities as well as the six in the previous paragraph (along with the equation) into *Mathematica*'s **Reduce** command but it doesn't seem able to handle it. Have I any hope of solving this system?

**Context:**

Any solutions correspond to *symmetric* states ($\nu=\nu\circ S$ where $S$ is the antipode) on the Kac-Paljutkin Quantum Group (something about which is said [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430687/the-irreducible-corepresentations-of-the-eight-dimensional-kac-paljutkin-quantum)) whose convolution powers converge to the Haar state.

**Subproblems:**

- It is not hard to see that these inequalities can't hold if $\mu_5=0$ for in this case we can't have $|\sum_{i}\mu_i|<1$ because $\sum_i\mu_i=1$.
- I am also interested in what happens when $x$ and $z$ are equal to zero.

Comment: Could you please include the Mathematica code you used?

Comment: Eh, basically Reduce[{the six inequalities and one equality}]... I used $\mu_i$ and $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Well, if you can spare me the effort to type it ...

Comment: Well the ELEVEN inequalities are above as is the equality so...

Comment: They are not copyable as Mathematica expressions. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: from where comes this system? it's possibe to solve a simpler one for the first case

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it is given in the context... basically I have a formula for the distance between the convolution powers of a symmetric state  $\nu$ and the Haar state that is given in terms of even powers of the five expressions above... if the above are less than one in absolute value the distance goes to zero.